# Test.LoadData throws Unknown field error

Tags: apex

I'm trying to use Test.LoadData.

CSV

```
Name, TEST_field__c
1,test1
2,test2
```

TestClass

```
 List<TESTObject__c> a = Test.loadData(TESTObject__c.sObjectType, 'TestData');
```

When I tried to load this csv from static resource, I caught error like this.

`System.StringException: Unknown field: TEST_field__c`

Can custom field data load from static resource?

**Absolutely same situation**

https://codeday.me/jp/qa/20190427/715216.html

Comment: did you remove the space inside: `Name, TEST_field__c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will just copypaste the [answer](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005l41QAA) that I found on the SF Forums for the same problem:

> There is an incideous little devil-in-the-details issue here, and it's known as the Byte Order Mark (BOM)(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding). In short, it's an invisible character that certain programs like Excel include when it encodes CSV content as UTF-8 (even though it's not recommended) and it causes Salesforce's parser to fail.
>
> You can view and change the file encoding of a CSV in programs like VSCode. I did this, changed the encoding to plain UTF-8, reuploaded the static resource and...VIOLA. Things worked